# Understanding loess delta1 and delta2 combination

Tags: c, r, fortran, loess

I am trying to track down how to get to delta1 and delta2 in the R *simpleLoess* function that is called by the *loess* function.

In the *simpleLoess* function there is a call

```
z <- .C(C_loess_raw, y, x, if (no.st) 1 else weights, 
            if (no.st) weights * robust else 1, D, N, as.double(span), 
            as.integer(degree), as.integer(nonparametric), as.integer(order.drop.sqr), 
            as.integer(sum.drop.sqr), as.double(span * cell), 
            as.character(surf.stat), fitted.values = double(N), 
            parameter = integer(7L), a = integer(max.kd), xi = double(max.kd), 
            vert = double(2L * D), vval = double((D + 1L) * max.kd), 
            diagonal = double(N), trL = double(1L), delta1 = double(1L), 
            delta2 = double(1L), as.integer(surf.stat == "interpolate/exact"))
```

Which calls some C code which itself calls some fortran code. Then the delta1 and delta2 are just extracted as:

```
one.delta <- z$delta1
two.delta <- z$delta2
```

That is called in the c function [here](https://github.com/andreas-h/pyloess/blob/master/src/loessc.c). That itself calls some fortran [here](https://github.com/andreas-h/pyloess/tree/master/src). At this point I'm at a loss -- any suggestions on how the actual `delta1` and `delta2` are calculated so that I can recreate it would be very helpful...